# How to animate a bell curve in R

Tags: r

I want to see the bell curve with different Means and Standard Deviations. I have searched it but I have failed to find the codes to make it.

I found it with HTML codes and the output of the curve can be find at the following link. https://www.geogebra.org/m/nrgtzj5a

Is it possible to generate the same animation plot in R?

Comment: Please advise me what is the reason for downvoting to improve the question?

Comment: Not my downvote but if you hover over the R tag here or read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 there is a specific format for asking a question. To summarise it for you, your question should include 1) Sample data 2) Show expected output 3) What you have tried (important). You only have 2) in your question as a link (which is again discouraged). Reading your question it feels like you want us to do your work. If you have made any attempt to solve please include it in the question. Try to follow the guidelines while posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make interactive plots like this you want to use the `shiny` package in `R`. To run the following code you will need to have the `shiny`, `magrittr`, and `ggplot2` packages installed (install with `install.packages(c('magrittr', 'shiny', 'ggplot2'))`). Here is a simple application that recreates the plot you link to:

```
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Bell Curve Example"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("mu", "M", min = -10, max = 10, value = 0),
            sliderInput("sd", "S", min = 0.1, max = 3, value = 1)
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )
    )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
        # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
        x    <- seq(-10, 10, length.out = 100)
        y <- dnorm(x, mean = input$mu, sd = input$sd)
        
        tibble::tibble('x' = x, 'y' = y) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
            geom_line() + 
            labs(x='', y='', title = 'm = mean, s = standard deviation') + 
            theme_minimal()
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @user330 you can attempt to run the code example given in RStudio. RStudio will access your localhost / 127.0.0.1 and show the animation. What is your level of familiarity/experience with RStudio?